# how to extract number values in between 3 keys?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this string: `page: 4, response: 5, alt: 99`

I want to extract the values into an array:

[4, 5, 99]

Here is my code, it there a way to improve it?

```
pattern = "page: d+?,response: d+?, alt: d+?";

    String first = origianlString.replaceAll(pattern, "$0"); 
    String second = origianlString.replaceAll(pattern, "$1"); 
    String third = origianlString.replaceAll(pattern, "$2");
```

Comment: Look into capture groups.

Comment: I don't think this question should not be posted on Stack Overflow. It belongs in Code Review.

Comment: guava provides a fancy splitter for that: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#withKeyValueSeparator(char)

Comment: This is trivially answered by reading the Javadoc, which explains capture groups.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
String regex = "\\D+?(\\d+)\\D+?(\\d+)\\D+?(\\d+)";
String input = "page: 4, response: 5, alt: 99";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    String first = m.group(1);
    String second = m.group(2);
    String third = m.group(3);
    System.out.println("[" + first + "," + second + "," + third+ "]");
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[4,5,99]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use RepalceAll

```
String str = "page: 4, response: 5, alt: 99";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

Answer (score -1):

Best bet would be to use the split method assuming that the values will **always** be separated by ","

For example:

```
String data = "page: 4, response: 5, alt: 99";
String[] split = data.split(","); //Get each individual entry
int[] values = new int[split.length]; //Create array to hold values
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) { //Go through each value
    String str = split[i]; //Get the string
    str = str.trim(); //remove whitespace
    String[] pair = str.split(":"); //Split to get key and value separate
    values[i] = Integer.parseInt(pair[1]); //Put int value into array
}
```